# Can't get access of phpmyadmin from command line

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have installed MAMP. It works fine from localhost:8888 and I can access phpmyadmin from localhost:8888/MAMP. In my application I am using zend framework 2. I am running basic Album module on my local host. But some how it's not running on local server. When I checked database in MAMP. There was nothing in there.

Where do I need to locate MAMP phpmyadmin access credentials in zend code?

Comment: Maybe this? Very uneducated guess. http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/content/installing_phpmyadmin.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering if you are confusing phpMyAdmin with MySQL?

phpMyAdmin is just a web based interface to MySQL. If the database isn't visible in phpMyAdmin it probably isn't created. You can either create the database in phpMyAdmin or at a MySQL prompt.

Once the database is created have another look at this page in the tutorial http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html it has the sql scripts you can run in either phpMyAdmin or a MySQL prompt to create the tables.

Once the database and tables are created edit

```
config/autoload/global.php
```

and

```
config/autoload/local.php
```

(again instructions included in the tutorial link above)

B.T.W. to access the MySQL prompt with MAMP type the following in your terminal;

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
```

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/using-mysql-command-line-with-mamp.html

Run this SQL to create and populate your table

```
CREATE TABLE album (
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  artist varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO album (artist, title)
    VALUES  ('The  Military  Wives',  'In  My  Dreams');
INSERT INTO album (artist, title)
    VALUES  ('Adele',  '21');
INSERT INTO album (artist, title)
    VALUES  ('Bruce  Springsteen',  'Wrecking Ball (Deluxe)');
INSERT INTO album (artist, title)
    VALUES  ('Lana  Del  Rey',  'Born  To  Die');
INSERT INTO album (artist, title)
    VALUES  ('Gotye',  'Making  Mirrors');
```

Comment: I changed all the things. I follow the zend documentation. But, I think, there is something wrong with MAMP port. I got error like this,
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Driver/Pdo/Statement.php:245 

Statement could not be executed

I have done same things showed up here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html Is there anything that I need to change because, I am using MAMP.

Comment: Can you see the database in phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Yes, Now it's there.. I made it from command line by the link you gave me. But there is no table inside that.

Comment: I have added the sql command in the answer you need to run in order to create the table. Run this from either phpMyAdmin or from the MySQL command prompt. If you are using the prompt first type "use album;" (or whatever your db is called - without quotes) if you are using phpmyadmin select the database and then click on the "sql tab" paste in the sql statement and click go

Comment: ok.. Thanks. I thought zend would take care of creating database and inserting just like doctrine 2. I am learning these stuffs. So, Mixed it up all the things..